# Can I decrypt an RSA algorithm using only the message I am wanting to decrypt, an "e" value and a "n" value?

Tags: cryptography

I have a ciphertext $c$ encrypted with RSA algorithm that needs to decrypt. I have the public key $(n,e)$.

Is it possible to decrypt with this amount of information?

Comment: The public key of RSA is exactly $(n,e)$, so are you asking how to attack RSA?

Comment: https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/RSA-survey.pdf

Comment: http://members.tripod.com/irish_ronan/rsa/attacks.html

Comment: Question is do you have single ciphertext or multiple encrypted under the same key.

Answer (score 2):

You have the public key. The whole point about public key cryptography is that the message is encrypted with the public key and must be decrypted with the private key, which you don't have.

The public key is not a secret: it is distributed publically so that people can encrypt messages for its owner. If you could decrypt the message knowing the cyphertext and the public key, RSA would be completely broken, because then anybody could decrypt any message. If anybody knows how to do this, they're keeping it a secret.

Comment: If he has more ciphertexts encrypted under the same key, there are some attacks.

Comment: The question says "a ciphertext" not "some ciphertexts".

Comment: Well, there was a similar question in crypto.StackExchange with 'a' and the accepted answer was based on multiple ciphertexts

Comment: @kelalaka OK, but I'm answering this question on Computer Science SE and I've chosen to answer the question that's been asked, rather than some other question that might have been asked instead. If you'd like to post an answer that deals with the case of having multiple cyphertexts, please go  right ahead.

Comment: No, actually, I totally agree with you. I've already supplied the document links as comments at the beginning. thanks.